# Unable to retrieve correct parameter value from get request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The problem that I am having is that if I pass a value of an optional parameter in my get request, I get the same result that I would if no value was passed.

**Route**:

```
   Route::get('/play/game/{new?}', [
        'uses' => 'GameController@getGame',
        'as' => 'game'
    ]);
```

**Controller**:

```
public function getGame($new = null) {
    $quotes = Quote::orderBy('created_at', 'dec')->paginate(50);       

    if(!is_null($new)) {
        if ($new == 'yes')
            $newgame = true;
    } else {
         $newgame = false;
    }

    return view('game', ['quotes' => $quotes, 'newgame' => $newgame]);      
}
```

**View**:

```
@if($newgame ==true) 
 {{Session::flush()}}
@endif

@if($newgame == false)
<h1>Not a new game</h1>
@endif
```

The second if statement in the view is just a test, and it is this statement that always executes. 
For reference, I am using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the route as follows:

```
Route::get('play/game/', [
        'uses' => 'GameController@getGame',
        'as' => 'game'
    ]);
```

and then when you call the `url`, pass the variable like this:

`play/game/?new=yes`

Then in your controller, you can check if the variable is set:

```
if($request->input('new')=='yes'
```

to check if the parameter is present:

```
$request->has('new')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
i think there is no need to put '?' symbol in parameter

```
Route::get('play/game/{new}', [
        'uses' => 'GameController@getGame',
        'as' => 'game'
    ]);
```

Comment: Actually, the ? symbol represents an optional parameter, so in the event that there is no value passed, Laravel wont go crazy and throw an error. You can read about it here:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Comment: ohh sorry. even i don't  about this.